# How to set element height but stay responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Using bootstrap 3 with mvc5.  I have a row of 5 fieldsets with radio groups.  I need the fieldsets to be the same height, despite the different number of radio buttons in each group.  If I set a height, the radio buttons overflow the fieldset when I go to small screen size.

I have tried setting the height to 100% and setting a height for the container, but that just causes the same issue.

My fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/battlfrog/rkpsv0jw/1/

```
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #527f03;
  padding: 0 15px 15px 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
.radio {
  width: 100%;
}

#radio-row {
  min-height: 200px;
}

#radio-row fieldset {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want each fieldset to be the same height why not just use

```
min-height:300px;

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #527f03;
    padding: 0 15px 15px 15px;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: I was doing that, and for some reason decided it was a bad idea.  It seems to be working now, so I will go with it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting padding in `%` worked for me.:)

Just changed your fieldset class padding to 10%

```
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #527f03;
    padding: 10%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rkpsv0jw/7/

Comment: Ok i added all the fieldset back again to verify and..ignore responsive -fieldset clas..i was trying something else and forgot to remove

Comment: Sorry, the fieldsets are still different heights.

Answer (score 0):

a pure JS solution:

you could make a quick comparison and then do the height styling looping twice through your fieldset tags,

here's some code that can work it out:

```
var fieldsets = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset')
var highest=0;
var b=0;
for (var i = 0; i<fieldsets.length ; i++){
 var a=fieldsets[i].offsetHeight;
 if(a<b){highest = b} else {highest = a};
 b = a;    
}
 for (var i = 0; i<fieldsets.length ; i++){
    fieldsets[i].style.height = highest + 'px'
}
```

although it would be more elegant to do it with a forEach this will work.